# .NET Core 2 - EF Core Error handling Save changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm used to Entity Framework 6 and my *base* repository Save() looks like this:

```
public void Save()
{
    try
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`DbEntityValidationException` is an expected error from Entity Framework if the object save is invalid. Now that I'm on a new .NET Core 2 project. What is the *expected* entity validation error type in Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Did you think of trying to see what exception is thrown?

Comment: "Exception" is always "unexpected". If you "expect" some "exceptional situation" (BTW, why you don't prevent it?) - it's your app-specific.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Looking through the GitHub issues, there is no `DbEntityValidationException` equivalent in Entity Framework Core. There's [a blog post](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/12/13/validation-in-efcore.html) (linked from [issue #9662](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9662) on GitHub), that gives a code example for performing the validation logic yourself, included here for completeness:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                       where e.State == EntityState.Added
                           || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                       select e.Entity;
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
            Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

`Validator.ValidateObject` will throw a `ValidationException` if validation fails, which you can handle accordingly.

There's a bit more information in the linked issue in case you run into issues with the validation attributes.

---

Note: The `Validator` class is located in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

Comment: Doesn't do referential integrity, just data annotation style validations.

Comment: There is also a TryValidateObject which lets you collect the errors without throwing an excepton.

Comment: If you need to include additional validations such as `MinLength` you may have to add the `validateAllProperties` bool parameter as: `Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext, validateAllProperties: true)`