# Why does my Validator not catch required-field errors

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement to change any null text fields to empty strings when saving. In my code below, which is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430619/net-core-2-ef-core-error-handling-save-changes/), `Validator.TryValidateObject()` returns `true` even when there are some null strings in the entity. Then the `dbContext.SaveChanges()` throws a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException` with an inner `SqlException` saying "Cannot insert the value NULL into column X."

Why does `Validator.TryValidateObject()` not catch this `null` column, and how can I fix it?

Catching the `SqlException` is awkward because it's hard to find out which column is `null`, not to mention the inefficiency of `try-catch`.

```
public static void SaveChangesWithEmptyStrings(this DbContext dbContext) {
    var entities =
        from e in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        where e.State == EntityState.Added
               || e.State == EntityState.Modified
        select e.Entity;
    foreach (var entity in entities) {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, validationContext, results))
            continue;
        foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
            if (result.ErrorMessage.Contains("Cannot insert the value NULL"))
                foreach (string name in result.MemberNames)
                    // Code to set the column to an empty string
    }
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```